# Column 'appWidgetProvider' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, motorola

I am working on a launcher application, currently I am including this launcher as an external library.

The launcher works for Android API level 16-23. I tested the launcher on every Android API level for samsung phones, alcatel for 21, and nexus from 21 until 23. I tested on tablets (Lenovo and Samsung) and it works fine.

The launcher is failing to get installed though on the Motorola phone, it gives the error **'appWidgetProvider' does not exist**. If I try to create an emulator with a nexus below API level 19 it gives the same error.

My question is why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

( The first thing that comes to my mind is that I am not currently finding the option to add a widget to the homescreen in the motorola, so it just doesn't exist. In that case what would be the best way to test for this and to disable it.

**Logcat**

```
04-06 05:41:51.383 1915-1929/com.arlind.catapulttesting2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: launcher-loader
    Process: com.arlind.catapulttesting2, PID: 1915
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'appWidgetProvider' does not exist
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
    at com.android.launcher3.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.loadWorkspace(LauncherModel.java:2146)
    at com.android.launcher3.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.loadAndBindWorkspace(LauncherModel.java:1646)
    at com.android.launcher3.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.run(LauncherModel.java:1751)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-06 05:41:51.393 1252-1464/system_process W/ActivityManager:   
    Force finishing activity com.arlind.catapulttesting2/com.android.launcher3.Launcher
```

**Application part in which it happens**

```
private boolean loadWorkspace() {
            // Log to disk
            Launcher.addDumpLog(TAG, "11683562 - loadWorkspace()", true);

            final long t = DEBUG_LOADERS ? SystemClock.uptimeMillis() : 0;

            final Context context = mContext;
            final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
            final PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
            final AppWidgetManager widgets = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            final boolean isSafeMode = manager.isSafeMode();
            final LauncherAppsCompat launcherApps = LauncherAppsCompat.getInstance(context);
            final boolean isSdCardReady = context.registerReceiver(null,
                    new IntentFilter(StartupReceiver.SYSTEM_READY)) != null;

            LauncherAppState app = LauncherAppState.getInstance();
            DeviceProfile grid = app.getDynamicGrid().getDeviceProfile();
            int countX = (int) grid.numColumns;
            int countY = (int) grid.numRows;

            boolean shouldResize = ((mFlags & LOADER_FLAG_RESIZE_GRID) != 0);

            if ((mFlags & LOADER_FLAG_CLEAR_WORKSPACE) != 0) {
                Launcher.addDumpLog(TAG, "loadWorkspace: resetting launcher database", true);
                LauncherAppState.getLauncherProvider().deleteDatabase();
            }

            if ((mFlags & LOADER_FLAG_MIGRATE_SHORTCUTS) != 0) {
                // append the user's Launcher2 shortcuts
                Launcher.addDumpLog(TAG, "loadWorkspace: migrating from launcher2", true);
                LauncherAppState.getLauncherProvider().migrateLauncher2Shortcuts();
            } else {
                // Make sure the default workspace is loaded
                Launcher.addDumpLog(TAG, "loadWorkspace: loading default favorites", false);
                LauncherAppState.getLauncherProvider().loadDefaultFavoritesIfNecessary();
            }

            // This code path is for our old migration code and should no longer be exercised
            boolean loadedOldDb = false;

            // Log to disk
            Launcher.addDumpLog(TAG, "11683562 -   loadedOldDb: " + loadedOldDb, true);

            synchronized (sBgLock) {
                clearSBgDataStructures();
                final HashSet<String> installingPkgs = PackageInstallerCompat
                        .getInstance(mContext).updateAndGetActiveSessionCache();

                final ArrayList<Long> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<Long>();
                final ArrayList<Long> restoredRows = new ArrayList<Long>();
                final Uri contentUri = LauncherSettings.Favorites.getContentUri(false,context);
                if (DEBUG_LOADERS) Log.d(TAG, "loading model from " + contentUri);
                final Cursor c = contentResolver.query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);

                // +1 for the hotseat (it can be larger than the workspace)
                // Load workspace in reverse order to ensure that latest items are loaded first (and
                // before any earlier duplicates)
                final HashMap<Long, ItemInfo[][]> occupied = new HashMap<Long, ItemInfo[][]>();

                try {
                    final int idIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LauncherSettings.Favorites._ID);
                    final int intentIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                            (LauncherSettings.Favorites.INTENT);
                    final int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                            (LauncherSettings.Favorites.TITLE);
                    final int iconTypeIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.ICON_TYPE);
                    final int iconIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LauncherSettings.Favorites.ICON);
                    final int iconPackageIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.ICON_PACKAGE);
                    final int iconResourceIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.ICON_RESOURCE);
                    final int containerIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.CONTAINER);
                    final int itemTypeIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.ITEM_TYPE);
                    final int appWidgetIdIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.APPWIDGET_ID);
                    final int appWidgetProviderIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.APPWIDGET_PROVIDER);
                    final int screenIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.SCREEN);
                    final int cellXIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                            (LauncherSettings.Favorites.CELLX);
                    final int cellYIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                            (LauncherSettings.Favorites.CELLY);
                    final int spanXIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                            (LauncherSettings.Favorites.SPANX);
                    final int spanYIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.SPANY);
                    final int restoredIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.RESTORED);
                    final int profileIdIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.PROFILE_ID);
                    //final int uriIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LauncherSettings.Favorites.URI);
                    //final int displayModeIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    final int hiddenIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            LauncherSettings.Favorites.HIDDEN);
                    //final int uriIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LauncherSettings.Favorites.URI); 
                    //final int displayModeIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    //        LauncherSettings.Favorites.DISPLAY_MODE);

                    ShortcutInfo info;
                    String intentDescription;
                    LauncherAppWidgetInfo appWidgetInfo;
                    int container;
                    long id;
                    Intent intent;
                    UserHandleCompat user;
```